# Ubuntu 14.04 - No wireless connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP laptop and I do not have any wireless connection.

I have followed the procedure given on this post [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), and I give here the generated file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10901227/.

Can anyone help me fixing this issue?

Regards,
Xavier

Comment: Have you disabled all your wireless? without the data in the diagnostic information we can not see how it is trying to work.

Comment: `sudo modprobe wl` and see if it works and it appears that you are just trying Ubuntu from the installation media

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
GrantBowman: My wireless is activated. It works OK when using Windows.
Jeremy31: With this command I get the following: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: @Jeremy31: I forgot to react about one of your remark. I am indeed trying Ubuntu from a stick. It is then not installed on my laptop at the moment. Do you think this has an influence on the issue?

Comment: Have you rebooted since running the wireless script?  If so you need to go into software and updates/Additional Drivers and select the broadcom STA driver to install

Comment: Yes I have rebooted. In the tab you indicated me, I have chosen the Broadcom STA, then I clicked <Apply Changes>. I was connected through eterneth while doing so. Nothing new apparently, my wireless is still not working.

Comment: @GrantBowman: I have typed ifconfig -a on a terminal, and I get only two entries: eth0 and lo. With the command nm-tool, the only device that appears is eth0. I am not sure whether these can help.

Comment: Since you have ethernet available `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and see if the wifi will work

Comment: I had the following: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10903014/. Wifi is still not working unfortunately.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep bcmwl`  But it is likely a false hope

Comment: Here is the result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10903073/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the bcmwl-kernel-source from a mirror site from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download) and install

For some reason Ubuntu decided to put a 3.16 kernel with a version of bcmwl that doesn't work 6.30.223.141 as it does't have the needed patch

If the answer works, please file a bug report, info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011078)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This settled the issue, my wireless connection is now working.

Comment: I am not familiar with bug reporting. I have followed the instruction given on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs. When typing `ubuntu-bug bcmwl-kernel-source` on a terminal, it is said that the problem cannot be reported as it is not an official Ubuntu package.

I did not find how to proceed. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I would file against Ubuntu if possible as it was their mistake mixing a kernel with a package that isn't compatible

Comment: Ok, I will try to find a way to open a new post in order to report this bug. Thanks again.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO and filed my own bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1449456)  You can click "This bug affects me" and there was a bug report over a month ago [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1432444)

Comment: Thanks for taking care of it and for the information. 

I am surprised: when I click on "Report a bug" via the URL [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/), I end up [there](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). I was trying to find the way to fill a report following the indication on this webpage yesterday, but at the end I was not able to find something. 

On the contrary, when I click on "Report a bug" on your page [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1449456) for instance, I can start filling a report easily.

Comment: (I have clicked "This bug affects me" on your report.)